# Manually edit full name mac users & groups

Tags: high-sierra

So I have a High Sierra computer with one administrator account it lets me log in on the

I believe I edited the advanced options under Users & Groups and now both terminal and the Users & Groups throw errors.

Is there a way to create a new account or edit the old one such that I can get back Administrative privileges again?

```
me is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I have administrative access to the hard drive if that helps through a second partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want create a new Administrator on your Mac, you need boot in Recovery Mode. (cmd+r at boot) .
If Filevault is activated, from Disk Utility, you unlock/mount the System Volume giving the password. (right click on the system volume).
You quit disk utility, then on top menu you select Utilities/Terminal
I suppose the System Volume name is "Macintosh HD", the command is :

```
rm /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

If no error message you reboot the Mac and then you will be invited to create a new administrator.

Then you can modify and repair your initial User admin account.